# Can't get an nping response through an Alcatel modem - but can get ping

Tags: ping

I am trying to use `nping` to ping 8.8.8.8 through an Alcatel W800 modem.  I need `nping` because eventually I will need the ability to set some things like destination-mac.  For now, I am just trying to use it like ping as a sanity test, to insure I know how to use the command!

When I nping 8.8.8.8 through other connections, like WiFi, using this command:

`nping 8.8.8.8 --icmp --icmp-type echo`

I get a response.

However, through the Alcatel modem, I get no response.  Now the key part: using the same network setup, if I use just `ping`, I do get a response.

I made a pcap of both exchanges (ping vs nping), and I see a few differences:

- the packets generated with ping are length 80
- the packets generate with ping have a "Timestamp from icmp data", according to wireshark

Vs nping:

- packets are length 28
- packets don't have a timestamp, even when I include `--icmp-orig-time now`, like this:

`nping 8.8.8.8 --icmp --icmp-type echo --icmp-orig-time now`

So what am I missing to make nping include that timestamp in the outgoing echo packets?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was set `--data-length` to higher, maybe the Alcatel throws out ICMP packets under a certain length or something.